# Stack Too Deep Error When Accessing Active Record Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have a user object and a character object that I generated.  The character object has a "belongs_to" relationship with the user object.

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

But whenever I try to create a new character or query for all of them it throws the below error:

```
Started GET "/characters" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-28 15:54:28 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by CharactersController#index as HTML
  Character Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "characters".* FROM "characters"
  Rendered characters/index.html.erb within layouts/application (15.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms

ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep):
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:84
```

My index action:

```
def index
  @characters = Character.all
end
```

My create character method:

```
  # GET /characters/new   
  def new
      @character = Character.new(:user_id => current_user.user_id)
  end
```

All the googling I've done pulls up some recursive issue, but I don't see how I could be calling anything recursively.

**EDIT**

My index.html.erb for the character model:

```
<h1>Listing characters</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @characters.each do |character| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', character %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_character_path(character) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', character, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Character', new_character_path %>
```

And my user model (created using Devise):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

I tried it in the rails console as well:

```
2.0.0p247 :002 > Character.all
  Character Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "characters".* FROM "characters"
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from /Users/mam8cc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:59
```

Comment: What does your User model look like?

Comment: And what does `characters/index.html.erb` look like?

Comment: should not be current_user.id in your new method instead current_user.user_id? probably this does not cause the stack level error, but it looks odd.

Comment: I've updated the question with the requested code.

Comment: stuff like this usually happens if you call a method from inside itself. i suggest using the debugging techniques described in this article http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the Rails code identified by the stacktrace:

```
# activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:59

def define_method_attribute(name)
  safe_name = name.unpack('h*').first
  generated_attribute_methods::AttrNames.set_name_cache safe_name, name

  generated_attribute_methods.module_eval <<-STR, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def __temp__#{safe_name}
      read_attribute(AttrNames::ATTR_#{safe_name}) { |n| missing_attribute(n, caller) }
    end
    alias_method #{name.inspect}, :__temp__#{safe_name}
    undef_method :__temp__#{safe_name}
  STR
end
```

The stack overflow is happening on the line that starts with `read_attribute`. Is there anything odd about the attribute names in the `Character` model? I'd recommend a careful look, and at the column names in the table as well.

Comment: The fields are id, name, gender, class, quote, and user_id.  I'm assuming class is what is causing the issue.  Sure enough, I ran a migration to rename the column and now all is well.  Thanks @zeteic.